# MySQL table setup for stock information

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am collecting about 3 - 6 millions lines of stock data per day and storing it in a MySQL database.

All of the data is coming from Interactive Brokers every piece of information comes with these five fields: Symbol, Date, Time, Value and Type (type being information on what type of data I am receiving such as price, volume etc)

Here is my create table statement. idticks is just my unique key but I almost never am able to use it in queries.

```
CREATE TABLE `ticks` (
`idticks` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`symbol` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`date` int(11) NOT NULL,
`time` int(11) NOT NULL,
`value` double NOT NULL,
`type` double NOT NULL,
KEY `idticks` (`idticks`),
KEY `symbol` (`symbol`),
KEY `date` (`date`),
KEY `idx_ticks_symbol_date` (`symbol`,`date`),
KEY `idx_ticks_type` (`type`),
KEY `idx_ticks_date_type` (`date`,`type`),    
KEY `idx_ticks_date_symbol_type` (`date`,`symbol`,`type`),
KEY `idx_ticks_symbol_date_time_type` (`symbol`,`date`,`time`,`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13533258 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50100 PARTITION BY KEY (`date`)
PARTITIONS 1 */;
```

As you can see, I have no idea what I am doing because I just keep on creating indexes to make my queries go faster.

Right now the data is being stored on a rather slow computer for testing purposes so I understand that my queries are not nearly as fast as they could be (I have a 6 core, 64gig of ram, SSD machine arriving tomorrow which should help significantly)

That being said, I am running queries like this one

```
select time, value from ticks where symbol = "AAPL" AND date = 20150522 and type = 8 order by time asc
```

The query above, if I do not limit it, returns 12928 records for one of my test days and takes 10.2 seconds if I do it from cleared cache.

I am doing lots of graphing and eventually would like to be able to just query the data as I need to it graph. Right now I haven't noticed a lot of difference in speed between getting part of a days worth of data vs just getting the entire day's. It would be cool to have those queries respond fast enough that there is barely any delay when I moving to the next day/screen whatever.

Another query I am using for usability of a program I am writing to interact with the data include

```
String query = "select distinct `date` from ticks where symbol = '" + symbol + "' order by `date` desc";
```

But most of my need is the ability to pull a certain type of data from a certain day for a certain symbol like my first query.

I've googled all over the place and I think I understand that creating tons of indexes makes the database bigger and slows down the input speed (I get about 300 pieces of information per second on a busy day).  Should I just index each column individually?

I am willing to throw more harddrives at things if it means responsive interface.

Basically, my questions relate to the creation/altering of my table. Based on the above query, can you think of anything I could do to make that faster? Or an indexing system that would help me out? Is InnoDB even the right engine? I tried googling this vs MyISam and after a couple of hours of this, I still wasn't sure.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Combine date and time into a DATETIME field
- Assuming Price and Volume always come in together, put them together (2 columns) and get rid if `type`.
- Get rid of the `AUTO_INCREMENT`; change to `PRIMARY KEY(symbol, datetime)`
- Get rid of any indexes that are the left part of some other index.
- Once you are using DATETIME, use date ranges to find everything in a single date (if you need such).  Do *not* use `DATE(datetime) = '...'`, performance will be terrible.
- `Symbol` can probably be ascii, not utf8.
- Use InnoDB, the clustering of the Primary Key can be beneficial.
- Do you expect to collect (and use) more data than will fit in `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  If so, we need to discuss your `SELECTs` and look into `PARTITIONing`.

Make those changes, then come back for more advice/abuse.

Comment: No, there are about 28 different types I am getting in. Bid, ask, last, all kinds of information on stocks, so I need the types. Working on everything else. I have created the table and I am modifying code my collector a bit to collect stuff. I am going to test a couple of days and see what happens. I never uncommented the innodb settings in the config file so that's probably terrible. Changed it to 1G, should be enough for my purposes now but I know I am eventually going to have to partition. Thanks :)

Comment: 28 types -- recommend you have more than one table -- one for stock trades, one for dividends, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a historical database, so MyISAM would work as well as InnoDB.  InnoDB is a transactional relational database, and is better suited for relational databases with multiple tables that must remain synchronized.

Your Stock table looks like this.

```
Stock
-----
Stock ID (idticks)
Symbol
Date
Time
Value 
Type
```

It would be better if you combine the date and time into a time stamp column, and unpack the types like this.

```
Stock
-----
Stock ID
Symbol
Time Stamp
Volume
Open
Close
Bid
Ask
...
```

This makes it easier for the database to return rows for a query on a particular type, like the close value.

As far as indexes, you can create as many indexes as you want. You're adding (inserting) information, so the increased time to add information is offset by the decreased time to query the information.

I'd have a primary index on Stock ID, and a unique index on Symbol and Time Stamp descending.  You could also have indexes on the values you query most often, like Close.

Comment: I'd rather not split the database up like that but if that is what I am forced to do, I appreciate the advice.